# Weight update rule for Rosenblatt's Perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, perceptron

I'm wondering if anybody can explain how Rosenblatt reached his formula for updating the weights of his Perceptron:

$\textbf{w}_{t+1} = \textbf{w}_{t} +\eta ( y_j - \hat{y}_j ) \textbf{x}_j$

It seems to me that the step function $h ( \textbf x^T \textbf w) )$ is disregarded in what looks to be (apart from the missing step function) a Stochastic Gradient Descent update formula. I know the step function cannot be differentiated, I'm just curious about the motivation and if I'm thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(y_j−\hat{y}_j)$ is 0 if the sample is at the correct side of the decision boundary. So there are only updates when the estimate is wrong.

Otherwise, let's assume $y_j=1$ and and we estimate the wrong label: $\hat{y}_j = -1$

The update becomes $\textbf{w}_{t+1} = \textbf{w}_{t} +\eta \textbf{x}_j$. That is, we move the direction of the vector $\textbf{w}$, which is perpendicular to the decision boundary, slightly towards the misclassified data point.

Note that $\textbf{w}_{t+1} \cdot \textbf{x}_j = (\textbf{w}_{t} + \eta \textbf{x}_j) \cdot \textbf{x}_j = \textbf{w}_{t} \cdot \textbf{x}_j + \eta \textbf{x}_j \cdot \textbf{x}_j = \textbf{w}_{t} \cdot \textbf{x}_j + \eta \Vert\textbf{x}_j \Vert > \textbf{w}_{t} \cdot \textbf{x}_j$
since $\eta \Vert\textbf{x}_j \Vert$ is positive (unless $\textbf{x}_j=\textbf{0}$).

Since the length of all samples is constant, every update is a finite update, although relative to the size of $\textbf{w}$ they will become smaller, and hence the angles will update with smaller steps eventually.

A symmetrical argument holds for $-1$ samples.

Since $\hat{y}_j = sign(\textbf{w} \cdot \textbf{x}_j)$, this means ultimately all estimates are correct when the data is linearly separable.